# Problems trying to access my VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, remote-desktop, google-compute-engine, rdp

I have a VM running on Google Cloud which I access remotely using an .rdp icon.
Starting last week I´m frequently getting the message "Remote Desktop Connection ‘Internal Error has Occurred’". Now I can only access my VM after many, many, many tries. I think the problem is related to the Google Cloud because I run another VM on Amazon (Amazon Web Services) from the same computer and I don't get any error messages.

Can anybody help me ?

My Computer Data: Samsung Intel Core i3
My Windows: Windows 10 Home Single Language / Version 2004 / SO Compilation 19041.985.
Google Cloud VM: Google Cloud Engine Virtual Machine / Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There could be lots of reasons for such issue. Please follow the documentation [Troubleshooting RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp) and [Troubleshooting Windows VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows) and update your question with your steps and details.

Comment: Could you add any information from the Windows Remote Desktop log?